# How to create a mailing and notification system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, notifications

We are currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in which users can ask questions to politicians. When a question gets asked, it's status is pending. When a Moderator approves it, its status becomes approved.

A Question can have several answers, each politician to whom the question is asked can give 1 answer. Users should be able to subscribe to a question. When this question gets a new answer, they should receive an email and if they happen to be online on the website a little notification would be a nice plus.

So basically I need some way to register that the Count of the Collection of Answers in a Question has changed.

I have basic knowledge of the Observer pattern. I have looked into this a bit more but I am not sure how to apply this to a full-blown Web Application.

I hope you guys can give me some suggestions/ ideas on how to solve this in the most simple manner. I have no idea which concrete classes I should create for this system to work.

Our Question model looks like this:

```
public class Question
{
public Question()
{
  AddressedPoliticians = new List<Politician>();
  Topics = new List<Topic>();

  Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
  Answers = new List<Answer>();
  QuestionSubscriptions = new List<QuestionSubscription>();
  SupportingUsers = new List<Regular>();
}

[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int QuestionId { get; set; }

[StringLength(250, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources.Resources),
  ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxCharsQuestionAchieved")]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Question_GeneralQuestionRequired")]
public string GeneralQuestion { get; set; }

[StringLength(1000, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources.Resources),
  ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxCharsExplanationAchieved")]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Question_ExplanationRequired")]
public string Explanation { get; set; }

//Whether the user is still writing the question
public bool IsTemplate { get; set; }

//Pending, Approved, Rejected
public QuestionState QuestionState { get; set; }
public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
public DateTime? JudgementDate { get; set; }

public virtual Regular Author { get; set; }

public virtual List<Politician> AddressedPoliticians { get; set; }

public virtual List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

public virtual Moderator LastEditor { get; set; }

public virtual City City { get; set; }

public virtual List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

public virtual List<QuestionSubscription> QuestionSubscriptions { get; set; }

public int FbShares { get; set; }
public int FbLikes { get; set; }
public int TwitterShares { get; set; }

public virtual List<Regular> SupportingUsers { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public int SiteVotes
{
  get { return SupportingUsers.Count; }
}
}
```

We also have a QuestionSubscription class. We can already create an instance of it via our website, but at this moment it doesn't actually do anything yet.

```
public class QuestionSubscription : Subscription
{
public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

public QuestionSubscription()
{
  LastMailSent = DateTime.Today;
  LastUpdate = DateTime.Today;
  WantsToReceiveEmail = true;
}

public void Update()
{
  //Something has changed
  //TODO Notify the user, don't know how yet ...
}
}
```

Lastly the superclass Subscription:

```
public abstract class Subscription
{
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
  public int SubscriptionId { get; private set; }

  public DateTime LastUpdate { get; protected set; }
  public DateTime LastMailSent { get; protected set; }

  [Description("Do you want to receive emails?")]
  public bool WantsToReceiveEmail { get; set; }
  public NotificationFrequency NotificationFrequency { get; set; }

  public virtual Regular Subscriber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this is an extremely broad questions but I would probably create an `Alert` class.  When things changes, create a new Alert with a flag saying its not been seen.  Once the user clicks on it, set it to flat its been seen.  As for firing these, could look at implementing a windows service which runs every so often to fire out emails etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about that, just don't know how much work this'll need and how it's best done ;) As for the Alert, that sounds like a good idea. I'm still a bit confused on how and what to notify when Answer Count changes :s